Craftcms 2.6.3000 Special Characters Missing and Dashboard Flicker
I am working with an inherited CraftCMS 2.6.3000.  Upgrade is in our future, but it will be awhile.
Various special characters (such as the chevron down icon used in dropdown buttons) are missing and replaced with other characters.
Additionally, the dashboard flickers when the window is maximized.
I'm new to craft, but I looked into the character encoding and changed the code in the layout template from:
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

to:
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

However, this has not affected the characters.
Is this a known bug for this version?
Thanks for your help in this

Suspect it's a CORS issue. Have you checked dev tools? I'd guess asset bundles may not be loading, hence the missing font files. You do know that even Craft 3 is now EOL and unsupported, right? Upgrading from 2 is going to be painful, maybe impossible. I'd suggest you simply dump the content and start over, with Craft 5, and use feed-me to import your legacy content.
